# Is it possible to change the site title color per page/post?

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, wordpress-theming

I am trying to have the front page website title in `#fff` (which it currently is) and then on other pages & posts where there is no image such as pages/posts/light background the website title in `#000`.

I've tried the solutions (bar the php solution as I was hoping for a more css related answer) and still unable to alter the title color on pages other than the homepage. One thing I have noticed is that the homepage is also a 'page'. Is it possible to use 'Page Id' to make those changes to individual pages?

Comment: Seems like your CMS generates a class home on body for homepage. you might just set the white color  like this `body.home #gk-bg-wrap #gk-header .site a { color:#fff }`

Answer (score 0):

Most Wordpress themes set classes to the Body of your HTML which can be used to dictate page specific styles. So in this example your Body will have the class "home" appended to it.

So you could set the default color to #000 then in your CSS use the body class to target the homepage only:

```
body.home .gk-logo-text{ color:#fff; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can achieve this by using `wp_head` action and `Conditional_Tags`.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'text_domain_title_css');

function text_domain_title_css()
{
    // Default homepage
    if (is_home() && is_front_page())
    {
        $output = "<style> .gk-logo-text.inverse > span{color: #fff} </style>";
    }
    //for all other page
    else
    {
        $output = "<style> .gk-logo-text.inverse > span{color: #000} </style>";
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and fully functional.

---

References:

- [wp_head](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head)
- [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
body.page .gk-logo-text.inverse > span{
    color: #000;
}
```

this will apply black color to site title in inner pages

Answer (score 0):

I can see that most pages do not have a title but that there is a h1 tag that can hold it called entry-title.

This is what the source code looks like:

```
<h1 class="entry-title"></h1>
```

So you can use the page-id that is created in wordpress to target a specific page and then its selector tag like this:

```
.page-id-xx .entry-title h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

The page id is visible in the url bar when you're editing a page. Hopefully your theme has a theme settings page where you can add some custom css. If not then you'll have to paste it in the style.css at a safe spot where you can hold all your custom css.

---